# How to migrate backup to AWS cloud ?(AWS Storage Gateway)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-storage-gateway

I am trying to create an application to migrate on-premise tape backup to the AWS cloud in an online way.

I went through the training where snowball service device as an offline mode of transportation and then saving into various options in S3(Glacier, Deep Glacier)

Is there a way we can do the same with online way? Basically, I am trying to build a utility to migrate on-premise tape backup to the AWS cloud at a minimal cost.
I want to create that using Java (spring boot) to do the task at a faster rate.

Thank you for any suggestions and help

I am trying to create an architecture flow diagram for now

Comment: What type of connectivity do you have between your on-premises system and AWS?

Comment: Have you considered using [Tape Gateway | Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/vtl/)?